# Оптимизация большой таблицы mysql, правильно ли?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть большая таблица history, ежедневно добавляется 1 млн строк. Делать выборку из одной таблицы очень ресурсозатратно и запросы выборки данных для определенного юзера за определенный интервал времени идут долго. Я думаю сделать разбиение таблиц по дням history_день_месяц_год, и промежуточную таблицу с днями когда юзера есть история за дни, чтобы не перебирать все таблицы, а только за те дни, когда записывалась история. Насколько имеет смысл партицирование в данной ситуации? Ведь иначе таблица будет увеличиваться до той поры, пока сервер уже совсем не справится с нагрузкой. Какие есть варианты решения?

Comment: Вместо портиций можно шардировать по самим юзерам. Завести штук 10-100 таблиц и писать для юзера с `id` в таблицу с номером `id % <число шардов>`. Плюс посмотреть бы на индексы в таблице. Плюс можно ввести холодное хранилище и выносить в него старые редко используемые записи.

Comment: Индекс по дате создания и id. Но таблица всё равно будет очень сильно расширяться.

Comment: @РодионЛарин начать стоит с того, что "делать выборку из одной таблицы" так или иначе выгоднее чем тот же по сути запрос но из нескольких таблиц (join). Как отметил Lexx918, вам необходимо перепроектировать индексы прямо в соответствии с запросами, которые вы будете выполнять. Либо же перепроектировать хранение данных, распределенных на нескольких серверах - но это уже вопрос не оптимизации запросов, но архитектуры решения в целом.

Comment: @timnavigate, фактически индекс это время и id пользователя. Но как будет работать выборка для миллиардов и сотен миллиардов записей

Comment: @РодионЛарин в таком случае, посмотрите этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/229300/393745, он подходит для вашей ситуации?

Comment: На этот вопрос невозможно ответить "в общем". В первую очередь, нужно знать какие запросы будут выполняться.

Comment: @RomanKonoval полностью согласен! Так как настраивать индексы "в вакууме" не понимая специфика запросов - заведомо неоптимальное решение. Вначале запрос, потом упираемся в производительность, только потом настраиваем индесы.

Comment: Выбираем данные из истории действий по user_id за период времени выбранный пользователем

Comment: @timnavigate, хотите сказать что для таблицы с миллиардами записей это панацея (индексы)?